# Removing the rabbitmq service from bluemix

Tags: rabbitmq, ibm-cloud

I am unable to remove the rabbitmq service from list of services in Bluemix. Every time i  request to delete the service, i get the following error message:

> The service broker reported an error during deprovisioning: Service
>   broker error: instance_id cf518624-b238-4fa1-8e9e-f7ca2897687e not
>   found Oct 20, 2015, 1:04:33 PM

Comment: Are you trying to delete from the console (UI) or the command line?

Comment: Can you open up a support ticket with our support team?  To open a support ticket please goto https://support.ng.bluemix.net.

Answer (score 4):

There were some problems with third party services giving that error message when creating or deleting a service. The issue is currently under investigation, even if some services now are working. Please try again and if the issue is still present you could open a ticket from [the portal](https://support.ng.bluemix.net) or sending an e-mail to support@bluemix.net.

To check the status of the platform please refer to [Bluemix Support - Status](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status). As you can see in the tab on the right "Updates" there is an open incident on this problem (Error provisioning and deprovisioning Third Party Services).